# Ruby - MultiThreading TCP Messages

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I am having an issue with a ruby server I am writing.

The server functions fine until you have more than one client attached, then it sends out the messages in a round-robin like way, when I want all clients to get the message at the same time.

The server is supposed to grab any clients that connects, but then wait till I issue a command. The problem is only one client is getting the command, when I enter a command again another client gets it and so on

**SERVER**

```
require 'socket'
mutex = Mutex.new
cv = ConditionVariable.new
server = TCPServer.open(2000)
@Comm="test"
Thread.new{
loop {  
    Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        client.puts("Client accepted")
        mutex.synchronize {
        cv.wait(mutex)
        client.puts("#@Comm")
        client.close
        }
    end
    }
}

loop {
system "clear" or system "cls"
print("Enter Command\n")
@Comm = gets()
mutex.synchronize {
cv.signal
   }
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
require 'socket'      # Sockets are in standard library

hostname = 'localhost'
port = 2000

loop {
begin
s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)
system "clear" or system "cls"
while line = s.gets   # Read lines from the socket
  puts line.chop      # And print with platform line terminator
end
s.close
rescue
next
end
sleep(0.5)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect your `mutex` to do in this code?  Is this your code, and what did you try?

Comment: Mutex holds the Thread until I enter a command, then it lets the thread continue, problem is that only one of the client threads actually continue.

Comment: `ConditionVariable.wait` does not do that -- when you call `.signal` it wakes up just one thread; the idea of `ConditionVariable` is to protect a resource that can only be accessed exclusively.

Comment: What other variable could I use in the place of the condition variable to run all threads? Or is this not a possibility with Ruby

Comment: Ok, I was half right and half wrong.  `.signal` only wakes up one thread on a conditionVariable.  But look at `.broadcast` on ConditionVariable, which I think does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.signal` on ConditionVariable only wakes up one thread, but `.broadcast` will go and wake up all that are waiting to be signaled.